# Missing \endgroup in csv longtable

Tags: longtable, csv, csvsimple

I am trying to read in a very long csv file to a longtable, but I am getting a `missing \endgroup inserted` error when compiling. I cannot figure out what is missing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
%\begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}%

    \toprule

    \bfseries Obsid & \bfseries Source & \bfseries Raw Soft Counts & \bfseries Raw Medium Counts & \bfseries Raw Hard Counts & \bfseries Background Soft Counts & \bfseries Background Medium Counts & \bfseries Background Hard Counts % specify table head
    \\&&\bfseries (.3-1.0 keV)&\bfseries (1.0-2.1 keV)&\bfseries (2.1-7.5 keV)&\bfseries (.3-1.0 keV)&\bfseries (1.0-2.1 keV)&\bfseries (2.1-7.5 keV) \\
    \midrule \endhead
    \bottomrule \endfoot
    \csvreader[
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},
    after reading={\catcode`\#=6},
    respect all,
    head to column names]%
    {counts_info_from_csc.csv}{RAW_COUNTS[.3-1]=\rawcountsS,RAW_COUNTS[1-2.1]=\rawcountsM,RAW_COUNTS[2.1-7.5]=\rawcountsH,BKG_COUNTS[.3-1]=\bkgcountsS,BKG_COUNTS[1-2.1]=\bkgcountsM,BKG_COUNTS[2.1-7.5]=\bkgcountsH}{\OBSID & \SOURCE & \rawcountsS & \rawcountsM & \rawcountsH & \bkgcountsS & \bkgcountsM & \bkgcountsH}%

    \end{longtable}
%\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

The csv file *is* being read in properly; when I try it with `tabular` instead of `longtable` it does read but the bottom gets cut off. I can't figure out what's missing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Replace the document class `standalone` by some ordinary document class. The `standalone` class can only be used with single objects of a fixed size. As a side note, don't use vertical lines together with `booktabs`.

Answer (score 3):

The `standalone` class adapts the size of the page to the contents of the document, and the `longtable` tries to adapt the columns to the size of the page, so this is too much flexibility.

The solution is to use either some standard document class or the `standalone` class with the `varwidth` option, like

```
\documentclass[varwidth=30cm]{standalone}
```

[image]

Note that due to the `booktabs` package the vertical lines are broken. Consider omitting the vertical lines.